# Boy on cross-country team who can push thoughts into others’ minds

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book. I have only read the first one hundred pages of the book and have not finished it and I am hoping to find the title of this book so I can buy it and see how it ends.

From what I remember, it was about a boy who runs on the cross-country team but it’s his first time and he is able to run really quick. He is also able to push thoughts into others’ minds. He has a mom and a dad that have strict rules on how to blend in with others and not stand out. He is invited into a prestigious college because he got a high mark on a standardized test. His parents are kidnapped and he then goes to the college on a plane but the authorities are after him for some reason.

Please help me find this book.